# Let $H$ be a group, $H_{ab}$ its abelianization. Is $Hom(H, \Bbb Z) \cong Hom(H_{ab}, \Bbb Z)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ be a group, $H_{ab}$ its abelianization. Is $Hom(H, \Bbb Z) \cong Hom(H_{ab}, \Bbb Z)$?

More generally, I am wondering if this is true if $\Bbb Z$ is replaced by an abelian group.

By the universal property of the abelianization we have an injective map from $Hom(H,G) \rightarrow Hom(H_{ab},G)$ for $G$ abelian.

I cannot show surjectivity. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is the universal property of the Abelianisation of a group.

In any homomorphism $\phi:H\to A$ with $A$ Abelian, all commutators
in $H$ map to the identity element of $A$, so $\phi$ induces
$\phi':H/[H,H]\to A$. And of course, given $\phi':H/[H,H]\to A$,
$\phi=\phi'\circ\pi$ where $\pi:H\to H/[H,H]$ is the projection
map is a homomorphism from $H$ to $A$.

Comment: I will accept as soon as I am able too (it's too early). Thanks for answering such a silly question!